# Error while trying to communicate between django and postgresql inside a docker

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, port

I've deployed Django+Vue application on server and changed psql ports from "5432:5432" to "5433:5433" because I'm running other applications on this server and this port is already in use, now I have a problem when making api requests, the error is:

```
Is the server running on host "db" (ip) and accepting
backend     |   TCP/IP connections on port 5433?
```

When I'm doing `docker-compose up` db service is saying:

```
db          | 2021-05-08 11:52:02.547 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.2 (Debian 13.2-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
db          | 2021-05-08 11:52:02.547 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
db          | 2021-05-08 11:52:02.547 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
db          | 2021-05-08 11:52:02.551 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
db          | 2021-05-08 11:52:02.555 UTC [27] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-05-08 11:51:10 UTC
db          | 2021-05-08 11:52:02.560 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

It says that it listening on port `5432`, while my docker-compose.yaml is:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  backend:
    container_name: backend
    build:
      context: ./mkstat_backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - static:/app/static
      - media:/app/media
    env_file:
      - ./mkstat_backend/.env.prod
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - backdb

  db:
    container_name: db
    build:
      context: ./docker/postgres
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    ports:
      - "5433:5433"
    env_file:
      - ./mkstat_backend/.env.prod
    networks:
      - backdb


  frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    build:
      context: ./mkstat_frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - frontend_dist:/app/dist
    depends_on:
      - backend


  nginx:
    image: nginx
    build:
      context: ./docker/nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./static:/var/html/static
      - ./media:/var/html/media
      - frontend_dist:/app/dist
    depends_on:
      - backend
      - frontend
    networks:
      - backdb

  redis:
    image: redis
    container_name: redis
    volumes:
      - redis:/var/lib/redis/data
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"

  worker:
    build:
      context: ./mkstat_backend
    command: celery -A mkstat worker -B
    container_name: celery
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
      - backend
    volumes:
      - ./mkstat_backend:/app


volumes:
  pgdata:
  static:
  static:
  media:
  frontend_dist:
  redis:

networks:
  backdb:
    driver: bridge
```

And my `docker ps` says:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                                 NAMES
8db91a231364   nginx               "/docker-entrypoint.…"   26 minutes ago   Up 26 minutes   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, :::80->80/tcp                     nginx
03d22372318a   mkstat_fb_worker    "celery -A mkstat wo…"   26 minutes ago   Up 26 minutes                                                         celery
3b94b9405ee1   mkstat_fb_backend   "/bin/sh -c 'gunicor…"   26 minutes ago   Up 26 minutes                                                         backend
8934add595fc   mkstat_fb_db        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   26 minutes ago   Up 26 minutes   5432/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5433->5433/tcp, :::5433->5433/tcp   db
d57b597a3445   redis               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   48 minutes ago   Up 26 minutes   0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp, :::6379->6379/tcp             redis
```

I'm kinda lost, please give me some advice, thank you!

Comment: The Docker Hub PostgreSQL image always listens on the standard PostgreSQL port 5432.  You need to use that port number for inter-container connections (which ignore `ports:`) and as the second port number in `ports:` (the two numbers can be different).

Comment: @DavidMaze Thank you, I seen that post, it didn't help, same error.

Comment: @karambaq  We don't know what you **did** after reading that post.

Comment: @jjanes I changed ports from 5433:5432 to 5433:5432